# How to disconnect the kitchen sprayer hose from its lead in a single-hole kitchen sink faucet

Tags: faucet, kitchen-sink

There's a pinhole leak in the mesh-reinforced PVC hose of our kitchen sink sprayer up where it connects to the hand-sprayer, so I need to find a replacement hose with the proper female-threaded connection on the sprayer end and the right kind of push-fit connector on the end that connects to the lead dangling down from the faucet beneath the sink (see photo).

How does the connection in the photo work? What steps must be taken to detach the white PVC hose? Do I take a pair of pliers and pull the blue piece with the "fingers" out, and then pull down on the PVC hose?

[image: kitchen sink PVC hose connection]

Comment: Have you tried grasping the outside part of the blue clip with pliers and pulling it away from the hose?

Comment: @Huesmann If I were to break it, I'd have to replace the entire faucet, which would entail  not only the expense but the time spent removing the garbage disposal in a corner sink with very cramped working area below. So I haven't experimented with tools, and have only tried to pull it away gripping with my fingertips.

Comment: The well-known manufacturer, BTW, was utterly useless: "Have you consulted a professional plumber? We don't have a support line any longer. Check our website for an installation video."

Comment: It shouldn't take too much force.  If you feel like you're gonna break it by pulling it off, you're probably using too much force.

Answer (score 3):

I tried with a pair of pliers, very gingerly, to extract the blue clip, and it turned out not to be an extraction but a rotation. The mechanism is like a hinge. I think the small screwdriver approach would have worked as well, as long as the handle of the driver were pushed away from you, not lifted towards you.

[image: opened clip]

Comment: Good picture! +1

Answer (score 2):

1. It appears there is a small hole in the clip; insert a small screwdriver and *gently* pry up to see if it pops loose.
2. On our current kitchen sink, I was unable to remove the existing hose without removing the whole faucet assembly from the sink. Instead, I purchased a similar (and better made) spray attachment with hose and spliced the two hoses together with a short stub of copper tubing and two hose clamps. This also made the hose conveniently longer.